# Using a boolean variable in theano

Tags: python, theano, autoencoder

I'm working on a bilingual autoencoder in theano. Taking [this tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/SdA.html) as reference, I created two monolingual autoencoders. Each takes a one-hot vector of a sentence and creates a latent representation which is a 100 dimensional numpy array. Then I concatenate these two (lat_1, lat_2) and here is where I'm having a problem. I want to mask one of the latent representations with 50% noise, so that one language needs to use the other latent representation as a clue to reconstruct itself. In theory this would alternate each epochs, so that both end up with optimum representations.

At the moment, I think I've only managed it with one side. My idea was to add a self.corrupted variable at the beginning and set it to 0 and after each epoch, change the variable so that it would alternate. Here's the code I've added for this.

```
def get_corrupted_concat(self, lat_1, lat_2, corruption_level):
    if self.corrupted == 1:
        corr_lat_1 = self.get_corrupted_input(lat_1, corruption_level)
        concatenated = T.concatenate((corr_lat_1, lat_2), axis=1)
        self.corrupted = 0
        print('corrupting lat_1')
    else:
        corr_lat_2 = self.get_corrupted_input(lat_2, corruption_level)
        concatenated = T.concatenate((lat_1, corr_lat_2), axis=1)
        self.corrupted = 1
        print('corrupting lat_2')
    return concatenated
```

While training, however, it only prints 'corrupting lat_1' once at the beginning and continues training. Does anyone know a way to get this to alternate?